# Bootstrap simple submit form inside modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, submit

I have a simple form which I am displaying inside a modal. When I want to submit it, it does somehow submit and reload the page, but the form isn't submitting to "example.php". I have tried to place the form opening tags everywhere but it's not helping. I just want a simple submit, nothing fancy with ajax or anything. What am I missing here?

```
<form method="post" action="example.php">
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleFormModal" aria-hidden="false"
     role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleFormModalLabel">Example Modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 pull-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: why not you try to put `<form></form>` inside modal HTML rather then modal HTML inside `<form></form>`

Comment: That's kinda what I meant with `I have tried to place the form opening tags everywhere but it's not helping` ;)

Comment: can you post `example.php` code

Comment: Thanks, because you asked for that, it made me realize that I was being silly. I am using laravel and I was posting to the right route, although it had errors (obviously) and it returned me back to the page I was trying to post from, my test page. I was hoping it would go to the actual `create` page and show the errors. I had to change my validation method and now it works. Thanks @Shehary :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned to do some more research before asking a question. If anyone for any reason is running into the same problem as me, just make sure that the `action=""` part in your code is working properly. I changed my action to google.com and it actually went to google. Rookie mistake perhaps but I thought it was a bootstrap modal issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@csrf` in the second line like this:

```
<form method="post" action="example.php">
@csrf
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleFormModal" aria-hidden="false"
```